# What's a website that has copyright-free images?

Tags: iphone, ios, image, background

Copyright free images/iPhone backgrounds/clipart that they let you put in your apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try having a look at http://sxc.hu

Comment: Or http://www.ImageFree.com